# How can I exclude last two child elements with CSS selector?

Tags: html, css

I want to draw `bottom-border` under some div elements inside their parent but except the last two, knowing that number of child element is changeable:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div>
One
   </div>
   <div>
Two
   </div>
   <div>
Three
   </div>
   <div>
Four
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to select all child elements except the last two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, something like

```
#parent > div:not(:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzv7srLj/)

Answer (score 9):

[`:nth-last-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) should do the job (combined with `:not`).

```css
#parent >:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)) {
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    One
  </div>
  <div>
    Two
  </div>
  <div>
    Three
  </div>
  <div>
    Four
  </div>
  <div>
    Five
  </div>
  <div>
    Six
  </div>
  <div>
    Seven
  </div>
</div>
```